# PL/SQL Before Trigger - Inherit column from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm very very very new to PL/SQL so excuse my ignorance on this subject, but I'd appreciate your help!

I have these 2 tables, let's say, RATINGS and GAMES.

Suppose that I want to inherit a value from the RATINGS table and insert it into the GAME table automatically depending on the GAMERATING (inheriting it from the RATINGS TABLE) I gave it.

On the GAME table we have: (GAMEID, GAMEPRICE, GAMENAME, GAMERATING, GAMEAGES, PUBLISHERID)

And on the RATINGS table we have: (RATINGID, RATINGCODE, RATINGAGES)

If I insert the following values into GAME: (1,50,'Lost','M') I want it to automatically insert the GAMEAGES from the RATINGS table using the GAMERATING as a basis for reading from the RATINGS table, specifically from RATINGCODE.

How would I go about on doing this?

All I know is I have to declare variables and insert the ages into them depending on the GAMERATING.

EDIT:

Managed to do it guys,

here's the format I used:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [triggername]

BEFORE INSERT ON [tablename]

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

[variables]

BEGIN

SELECT [columns to populate variables] INTO [variables] FROM [second table] JOIN [first table] ON [secondtableid] = :New.[firsttableid] GROUP BY [columns to pop variables] ORDER BY MAX([firsttableid])

:New.[firsttablecolumn] := [variables]

END

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Bad idea. There's a basic rule - Do Not Implement Business Logic In Triggers. There's more logic here than should be put into a trigger. Triggers are for minor stuff - filling in primary keys from sequences, populating "maintenance date" and "add date" columns, that kind of thing. To do what you're looking at here I suggest you write a function to handle doing the INSERT into GAME and all the other logic. Best of luck.

Comment: I know this is a bad idea, but it's for a class, and I'm really stuck

Comment: I agree with Bob here, just to be clear. So you have `GAME (GAMEID, GAMEPRICE, GAMENAME, GAMERATING, GAMEAGES, PUBLISHERID)` and you say you insert `(1,50,'Lost','M')` which value is which column?

Comment: If you've got an answer to the question, you can (and should) post it as an answer, not an edit. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: To answer Jorge's question, you would look at 'M' which is the rating column and compare it to the GAMERATING table. From there you would input the ages into the GAMEAGES column from the RATINGAGES column in GAMERATING. I hope I was clear with my explanation, I'm not a native English speaker!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [triggername]
BEFORE INSERT ON [tablename]
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
[variables]
BEGIN
SELECT [columns to populate variables] INTO [variables] FROM [second table] JOIN [first table] ON [secondtableid] = :New.[firsttableid] GROUP BY [columns to pop variables] ORDER BY MAX([firsttableid])
:New.[firsttablecolumn] := [variables]
END
```